# Groovy read json-file, add new key : value and write back (Jenkins)

Tags: java, json, file, jenkins, groovy

I want to read a json string out of a file, add a new key : value and write it back to the file.
with groovy-script during Jenkins-build.
file:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

I tried the following:

```
def setValue(String filepath, String key, value){
    String fileContent = readFile(filepath)
 
    Map jsonContent = (Map) new JsonSlurper().parseText(fileContent)
    jsonContent.put("${key}", "${value}")
 
    writeFile(file: filepath, text: JsonOutput.toJson(jsonContent))
}
```

but getting the following error:

```
exception: class java.io.NotSerializableException
[Pipeline] echo
message: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick answer

You can use the functions `readJson` and `writeJson` as described [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/).

### Long answer

Jenkins from time to time backs up the status of the pipeline to be able to resume it in case of failure. During this backup step, it tries to serialize every element in the current context of the pipeline. `NotSerializableException` notifies you that you have a not serializable object in your context (stack or heap) which prevents the pipeline from being serialized. Therefore try to only use serializable objects. If it is not possible, you can annotate functions that use such objects with `@NonCPS` to tell Jenkins not to atempt to back up the pipeline during the execution of that function.

Comment: getting the same error using this:

`def setValue(String filepath, String key, value){
 String fileContent = readFile(filepath)
    println "### file load into string {fileContent}. ${fileContent}"
    def jsonContent = new JsonSlurper().parseText(fileContent)
    println "### JsonSlurper created."
    jsonContent.put(key, value)
    println "### ${key} : ${value} added."
    
    writeJSON(file: filepath, json: fileContent)
    println "### write back file."
    commitChanges(filepath, key, value)
    println "### ### commit the changes."
}`

Comment: The `NotSerializableException` is most likely caused by the instance of `JsonSlurper` you create, because it most lileky does not implement `Serializable`. As stated in the reply, you can get around this either by using `readJson` and `writeJson`, since this avoids creating an instance of `JsonSlurper` or annotating the method with `@NonCPS` to prevent Jenkins from backing up the pipeline during the execution of the function.